# C# Linq using arrays inside where

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I would like to output all values in the filename array and filter them out through the Where Instruction. I tried to loop it. The problem is, the values are displayed twice.

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path, "*.TXT", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
            where line.Contains(Filename[i])
            select new
            {
                File = file,
                Line = line
            };
foreach (var line in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{line.Line}");
}
```

Is there a Problem with my logic or am i Using Linq wrong ? 
[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include some sample input (i.e. a representative list of files that you're processing and their contents) and sample output?

Comment: Try to create minimal reproduction set. For example, target a single directory with single file in it. Are the values displayed twice in this case?

Comment: The filenames may appear in more the one subfolder.  So do you want to include the full path names to make files names unique?  Or filter duplicates using Distinct()?

Comment: I'm not going to comment on what your algorithm is supposed to do and what possible optimizations there are, but you need to realise that the string `aabc.txt` contains the string `abc.txt`.

Comment: The filenames should be unique one and even if it is not bad the double is also  filtered out

Comment: Could you, please, describe the problem in plain English? So you have `*.txt` files in some `path`; now you want to enumerate the files *such that* (what is the condition(s), please?)

Comment: I have a Txt that contains a article numers
K420161.txt
K231356.txt
K123466.txt
ect. 
i want to Filter all Already existing K numbers 
IF K420161 exist then dont display it to me

Comment: That is not at all what your code seems to be doing? Your question shows no evidence of duplicates?

Comment: What is the type of `Filename`?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Filename it a string[] and I need a way to list the whole content of this string[] in the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### After question is edited:

Use this code to get existing files:

```
var txtPath = Path.Combine(dirPath, txtFileName);
var txtLines = File.ReadAllLines(txtPath).ToList();
var filesFound = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath, "*.DST", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                 where txtLines.Contains(Path.GetFileName(file))
                 select new
                 {
                     File = file,
                     Line = Path.GetFileName(file)
                 };

foreach (var line in filesFound)
    Console.WriteLine($"{line.Line}");
```

Use this code to get missing file(name)s:

```
var existingFiles = filesFound.Select(s => s.Line).ToList();
var missingFiles = txtLines.Except(existingFiles);
```

Or:

```
var txtPath = Path.Combine(dirPath, txtFileName);
var txtLines = File.ReadAllLines(txtPath).ToList();
var filesMissing = txtLines.Except(from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath, "*.DST", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                   where txtLines.Contains(Path.GetFileName(file))
                                   select Path.GetFileName(file));

foreach (var line in filesMissing)
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

**The 2nd has at least twice better performance.** Especially if you don't need filePath at all --> since missing files don't have one.

---

### For Original question:

Maybe you have the duplication because either there is 2 file in your foder but you are using the same filename for check or there is 2 line in your file, that matches with the filename.

### What is more important to answer your question is:

Do you want to **filter out files that has its own name within**, or do you want to **get all files only once when they have their own name within**?

### You chose the former, so the solution:

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.TXT", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
            where !line.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file))  //note the exclamation mark, this is how you filter
            select new
            {
                File = file,
                Line = line
            };

foreach (var line in files)
    Console.WriteLine($"{line.Line}");
```

You probably noticed that you don't need the array.

Comment: I dont want to be inside the Foreach loop since it displays my output twice

Comment: It displays twice only because you have *FileName[i]*, where ***i* is always *0***, not because the *foreach* itself.

Comment: i inrement it inside my loop look at the bottom i++; 
the problem it filters FileName[0] and Filename [1] but the filtered Content does diesplay in the Second round of the Loop

Comment: i think the Dublication is there
 since they are two Files K420161.Txt and one K464202.TXT and inside the foreach the Display loop is 2x Triggerd, one time with the Filter the other times without
But i cant let out the 1. Foreach since it runs the . objekt array.
I cant let out the Dispay Loop since it runs on Files,

Comment: filter out files that has its own name within,

Comment: Oooooh! So my 1st assumption was good that you have 2 files indeed in you folder! Nice. The first `foreach` is unnecessary, since `from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles()` does the enumeration! Its a brother of `Directory.GetFiles()`. But you want to keep the display foreach! You only want to get rid of the `foreach` with `var objekt in Directory.GetFiles()`

Comment: yeah figuered it out this is the problem 
How filter out the Filenames from my FileName Array ? 
where !line.Contains(objekt) should look like,
where !line.Contains(Filter all stuff out inside this array)

Comment: Is this now prints what you expected?

Comment: The Problem is.. it doesnt fitler any filenames if i Remove the ! mark nothing is displayed

Comment: Can you tell me what is the exact content (not an example) of your 2 files?

Comment: Editet a picture to the Question

Comment: Wow and you have more of these .txt files or always 1?

Comment: every name is unique 
This is for Testing i am expectet to do it with around 50000 filies  in like 130 Subfolders

Comment: Yes, you have a lot of .DST file all unique, but do you have more than 1 .txt file as well? All .txt will be multiline?

Comment: only 1 .Txt File Multiline

Comment: Do you succeed to progress with the project? The `Directory.EnumerateFiles` function is the best choice for big data.

Comment: I've added inside the Query 
from DSTFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.DST", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
if i now try with  ! (not) it displays K4206969,K9696420,K139951,K6969420 without the not only K139951, and K4206969 (The files that exist)

Comment: But i dont trust the result of the code since it only works 1 way as intended

Comment: @SpreadAnarchy Okay. I've edited the answer to show you how to do this.